# Clean Architecture: how to properly authenticate users

Tags: node.js, express, architecture, clean-architecture

I am making a project using Express and Nodejs.

I am learning how to implement learning how to implement clean Architecture properly.

I've made so far a Entity whose is a Balance (income/outcome).

But, in order for a particular user to be able to insert a new Balance, it's needed to be logged in.

So, in the Controller, I am receiving a `Request` which has a `body` with the `income data` and headers with the `authorization token`.

This controller makes the validations and forward the `body` as a `DTO` to the `CreateBalanceUseCase`.

My problem is that when i reach the `CreateBalanceUseCase`, I should call the `data-access` in order to save the `data` on the Database. But, the `authorization token` should be validated calling the `AuthorizationDataAcess` in order to find a user with same `authorization token`. But doing so, I violate the `Clean Architecture` I guess, right? Because I am trying to access the `data-acces` of the `Authorization`(aka User) inside the `BalanceUseCase`.

Also, on my database, I have a `1-n relation` of the UserId with the Balance. So I can know what `balance` belongs to what `user`. So, also in order to save a Balance, I need to get the userId.

My second approach was create a Express Middleware that authorize the client and returns a userId, so whatever I must do through the app that needs authorization, It must use this middleware.
The problem is that I must access the `data-access` layer on the `presentation layer`

Whats the best practice in this situation? Or am I getting the `Clean Code Architecture all wrong?`

If there is any code or something else I could do to clarify more my question, feel free to comment it out.

Best regards.